# From CSV columns to Dictionary- with Average? Python

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, average

I have a csv file with first line Student Names and the other lines are the Students' Grades:
david,barack,jack
60,80,78
100,50,92

I want to creat a dictionary with keys=Student Names and Values=Average grade:
{'david': 80, 'barack': 65, 'jack': 85}

I want the code to still work if I'll add more students and/or grades.

What would you do?

Thx

Comment: Can you be more elaborate? The structure is very unclear. Which marks corresponds to which student? Like Jack has no marks in this case

Comment: Okay, it's column wise? But how many subjects?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following.

```
import csv
f=open('nameofcsvfile.csv')
reader=csv.reader(f)
d={} #dict to store avg
c=0
name_list=[] #list to store students name
no_of_data=0

for line in reader:
    if(c==0):
        for j in line:
            d[j]=0
            name_list.append(j)
        c+=1
    else:
        no_of_data+=1
        k=0
        for j in line:
            d[name_list[k]]=d[name_list[k]]+int(j.strip())
            k+=1
for keys in d:
    d[keys]=d[keys]/no_of_data
print(d)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thx

Answer (score 0):

You can do as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("filename.csv")

dicts = {}
i=0
for name in df['Names']:
    dicts[name] = df['Grades'][i]
    i += 1

print(dicts)
```